# I recently upgraded ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 14.04 and now its showing bootloop

Tags: boot

I tried to upgrade ubuntu 12.04 Lts to 14.04 Lts (trusty tahr).my connection is bit laggy and had losted connection 4-6 times.everytime after connection loses next time it will ask for partial upgrade.but I cancelled those partial upgrade and continue to download remaining upgradation package downloading.Atlast the whole package got downloaded and installed.then after that a rebooting took place.after that am seeing some errors.i didn't get any idea of this.could anyone help me pls.either i've no ubuntu 14.04 iso for reinstalling nor repairing.pls help

Comment: What kind of errors you see now? Are you able to boot into Ubuntu or Ubuntu recovery.